# encounter error while i trying to build a LSTM model to encode and decode

Tags: python, keras, lstm

First,I just start to learn ML,I am trying to build a model base on LSTM. All of my input data is just number(int or float),However i keep encountering a error message"All inputs to the layer should be tensors".I think the problem maybe the data structure about the input data maybe list or something,but i am not quite familiar with the data structure about python.Thanks for your reading.
Here is my code:

def lstm(data,window_size):

```
encoder = Dense([ LSTM( output_dim=window_size-4, input_dim =window_size, activation='tanh' ,name="Dense", return_sequences=True) ])(data)
decoder = Dense([ LSTM( output_dim=window_size, input_dim =window_size-4, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True) ])(encoder)
autoencoder = Sequential()
auto_e = Model(input=encoder, output=decoder)
autoencoder.add(auto_e)
autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
autoencoder.fit(data,data, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=32)

dense_layer_model = Model(inputs=autoencoder.input,
                                 outputs=autoencoder.get_layer('Dense').output)

dense_output = dense_layer_model.predict(data)

print ("shape=",dense_output.shape)

print (dense_output[0])
return dense_output[0]
```

Comment: Please add `keras` tag to your question. BTW it is not enough to know Python, you also need to know `keras`.
For your question, please read this "gentle" blog post about LSTM encoder-decoder https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-autoencoders/

Comment: yap, i know about keras,but i think the problem is bout the dc at the input data